# Python: TypeError in referencing item in JSON feed

Tags: python, json

First, here is a sample JSON feed that I want to read in Python 2.7 with either simplejson or the built in JSON decoder. I am loading the .json file in Python and then searching for a key like "Apple" or "Orange" and when that key is found, I want to bring in the information for it like the types and quantities.

Right now there is only 3 items, but I want to be able to search one that may have up to 1000 items. Here is the code:

`{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "Apple": [
                {
                    "type": "Gala",
                    "quant": 5
                },
                {
                    "type": "Honeycrisp",
                    "quant": 10
                },
                {
                    "type": "Red Delicious",
                    "quant": 4
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Banana": [
                {
                    "type": "Plantain",
                    "quant": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Orange": [
                {
                    "type": "Blood",
                    "quant": 3
                },
                {
                    "type": "Navel",
                    "quant": 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

My sample Python code is as follows:

```
import simplejson as json

# Open file
fjson = open('/home/teg/projects/test/fruits.json', 'rb')
f = json.loads(fjson.read())
fjson.close()

# Search for fruit
if 'Orange' in json.dumps(f):

    fruit = f['fruits']['Orange']
    print(fruit)

else:

    print('Orange does not exist')
```

But whenever I test it out, it gives me this error:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Was it wrong to have me do a json.dumps and instead should I have just checked the JSON feed as-is from the standard json.loads? I am getting this TypeError because I am not specifying the list index, but what if I don't know the index of that fruit?

Do I have to first search for a fruit and if it is there, get the index and then reference the index before the fruit like this?
`fruit = f['fruits'][2]['Orange']`

If so, how would I get the index of that fruit if it is found so I could then pull in the information? If you think the JSON is in the wrong format as well and is causing this issue, then I am up for that suggestion as well. I'm stuck on this and any help you guys have would be great. :-)

Comment: This way you might have several apples in a list, how are you going to deal with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `f` type is `list`, it's a list of dictionary's with sub dictionary.

`if 'Orange' in json.dumps(f):` Will iterate the list and look at each item for `Orange`.

The problem is that `f['fruits']` is a `list` so it expects an `int` number (place)
and not a dictionary key like `['Orange']`

I think you should check your structure **like @kindall said**, if you still want to extract `Orange` this code will do the trick:

```
 for value in f['fruits']:
    if 'Orange' in value:
        print value['Orange']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Kobi. Adding the for statement before the if statement in my code helped and I was able to loop the data. If I run into any further issues, I will update the thread.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the data structure has a list enclosing the dictionaries. If you have any control over the data source, that's the place to fix it. Otherwise, the best course is probably to post-process the data after parsing it to eliminate these extra list structures and merge the dictionaries in each list into a single dictionary. If you use an `OrderedDict` you can even retain the ordering of the items (which is probably why the list was used).

Answer (score 0):

The square bracket in the line `"fruits": [`  should tell you that the item associated with `fruits` is (in Python parlance) a `list` rather than a `dict` and so cannot be indexed directly with a string like `'Oranges'`.  It sounds like you want to create a `dict` of fruits instead.  You could do this by reformatting the input.

Or, if the input format is fixed: each item in your `fruits` list currently has a very specific format.  Each item is a `dict` with exactly one key, and those keys are not duplicated between items.  If those rules can be relied upon, it's pretty easy to write a small search routine—or the following code will convert a list-of-dicts into a dict:

```
fruits = dict(sum([x.items() for x in f['fruits']], []))
print fruits['Orange']
```